# How do I find folders containing no recently modified files?

Tags: bash, find, osx

I have a directory that gets a lot of data dumped into it, and I want to find all directories whose contents haven't been modified recently (e.g., in the last 5 days). I'm trying to compose a call to `find` that does what I'm looking for, but I'm starting to wonder if this is more complex than what find can handle. Here's what I've tried, which isn't doing quite what I expect:

```
find "$DUMP_DIR" -type d -d 2 \
    -execdir bash -c 'find . -mtime -5 >/dev/null 2>&1' \; \
    -prune
```

The directory structure is laid out like `$DUMP_DIR/category{1,2,3,4,5}/thing*` more or less. I want to know what `thing*` directories have had new data dumped somewhere inside of them recently. The naive solution `find "$DUMP_DIR" -type d -d 2 -mtime +5` will match more than I want.

I expected that the `-execdir` expression will find out whether any directory contains something modified in the last five days (returning nonzero if nothing is found), but I guess it doesn't quite do that.

I'm stuck with the BSD find installed on OS X. I'd also rather not install anything not already a part of the standard command line utilities. What's the most reasonable way to do this?

Comment: I feel you...  BSD find is truly hideous. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this will do what you need. It looks through each directory in turn and checks that there are no "recently modified" files.

```
find * -type d |
    while read DIR
    do
        LINES=$(find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -5 -print -quit)
        test -z "$LINES" && echo "$DIR NOT RECENTLY MODIFIED"
    done
```

If the `find ... -maxdepth 1` doesn't work for your situation, feel free to change it to something like this

```
LINES=$(find "$DIR" \( -type d -prune \) -o \( -type f -mtime -5 -print -quit \))
```

And if you want to count the number of items recently modified (or if `-quit` isn't available), this will work

```
LINES=$(find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -5 | wc -l | tr -d' ')
test 0 -eq "$LINES" && echo "$DIR NOT RECENTLY MODIFIED" || echo "$DIR has $LINES recent file(s)"
```

Comment: This looks reasonably good assuming that the file names aren't pathological. I don't suppose there's any way for the `$(find ... | wc -l)` to terminate immediately upon encountering the first file matching the criteria, is there? After all, I don't really need to count the number of recently modified files, I just want to know if there's at least one.

Comment: It will handle filenames containing pretty much anything except `\n`. If your version of `find` supports it, you can try adding `-false` after the `-print` to exit as soon as a match is made.

Comment: At least on the version of find in OS X, adding `-print -false` at the end of `find ... -mtime -5` doesn't prevent it from continuing to find additional files with an mtime within the last five days.

Comment: I've updated the Answer to provide the optimisation you're looking for (i.e. `-quit`). On my `find` this works effectively.

Comment: Strangely, `-quit` is not documented in OS X in `man find`, but it works if used.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood the question this can be done quite simply with

```
find . -mtime +5 -exec bash -c 'echo "${0%/*}"' {} \; | sort | uniq
```

Comment: The parameter expansion inside your echo statement does not correctly grab the directories of interest. If the `thing*` directories themselves contain directories with files older than 5 days, you won't print the `thing*` directory correctly. Also this may fail for files with pathological names, but that's probably not a problem in my case.